# XAMPP error 403 on fresh install

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, xampp, http-status-code-403

I just installed XAMPP on my Ubuntu 9.10 box according to the instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=223410) and as far as I can see, everything was followed exactly per instructions, including setting up the soft link to my folder.  When I try to browse to http://localhost/ everything works fine, and the XAMPP page comes right up, but when I try to browse to http://localhost/me or http://localhost/me/index.html i get an error 403 message.  My folders and files inside are set to 755 permissions, and I'm not seeing anything that looks like an issue, but I don't really know how to troubleshoot this.  Does anyone have any ideas what I can look at and change to get this working right?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution finally.  I had to reverse the softlink stuff so that instead of the /opt/lampp/htdocs/$USER pointing to ~/public_html it went ~/public_html to /opt/lampp/htdocs/$USER.  making this change let me work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that permissions are correct on your DocumentRoot, but also every folder above that in the tree. Whatever user your apache is running as needs to be able to cd through those folders. What do your apache error_logs say about these 403 errors?

Second, why are you using XAMPP in ubuntu? Installing LAMP in ubuntu is really as easy as a single command, and you'll end up with a far more secure and standardized environment than you will with XAMPP.

If this server is for development only, XAMPP is probably okay, but don't even think about using XAMPP for a production site - that's not what it was made for, and you're just asking for trouble if you do that.

Comment: The production site is hosted by Peak.  I'm just building the site here.  I installed XAMPP as the link in the question was the first link on my search results, looked easy, and set up quickly.

Comment: the error message is "[Tue Dec 08 19:57:20 2009] [error] [client ::1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /opt/lampp/htdocs/me" but according to the instructions, it should be ok.  Can I allow it?  Or do I need to go another route?

Comment: Okay, well when looking for support from peers and from the ubuntu community, you'll likely have much better luck when using the LAMP stack that you can install via apt/synaptic/etc, than you will with XAMPP.