# Error 403 with XAMPP on Ubuntu with created files and folders

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, xampp, http-status-code-403

I'm used to work with `XAMPP` on `Mac` without problems, using it on `Ubuntu` probably giving me some user permission problem. I've set the `XAMPP` security as the guide too.

I've installed and tested everything with `XAMPP` site guide without problems but this:

if I use an `ftp client` with XAMPP ftp user to create and edit files in `htdocs` folder (I'm using `gedit` with [ftp client plugin](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-ftp-browser/), everithing works fine.

If I paste a folder with an existing project in `htdocs` folder I get `Error 403` by testing it with my web browser.

I've also followed the [guide here](https://serverfault.com/questions/92477/xampp-error-403-on-fresh-install) without success.

What should I do to fix the problem? I'm not a master with `Ubuntu` but I can use the shell with instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, it does sound like a permissions problem. If you know the user that apache runs as, chown the files to that user/group. You can find the Apache user, by looking in `httpd.conf`, there are two lines 'User' and 'Group'.

Alternatively, you could find the user/group of the files you uploaded with FTP (which you have said work). Run: `ls -l` on the directory and note the username.

Once you have the user and group, you can apply that to one of the directories you copied, by running:

```
cd /path/to/directory
chown -R user:group *
```

(that will recursively set the user and group for all files and directories under the current one).

Hopefully that works for you. If not check the permissions (again, running `ls -l`) and ensure the user has read access. You can set the permissions with `chmod`.

You might also want to check your .htaccess file or your httpd.conf file for any directory restrictions, but first try to set the permissions.

Comment: You can of course, change the User and Group in httpd.conf to whatever your local username is (or whatever user you will be uploading as, etc) - you may still need to take ownership of the files though.

Answer (score 1):

Here are instructions for XAMPP how to avoid this problem by running XAMPP under your own user account:

http://blog.mfabrik.com/2010/12/22/local-xampp-development-and-unix-file-permissions/

Comment: none of the answers worked for me, finally I've changed the folder htdocs permissions to let it works with my user